# post data inside clone div angularjs ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Clone div is repeating, when I click add button.
How can I post the fields inside clone div.

```
<div class="row" id="append-row">
            <div class="clone-div-{{count}}" id="clone-div">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="chapters.chapter.title">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
                        <label>Select Language</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" ng-model="chapters.chapter.languageID" ng-options="value.ID as value.language for value in technical.languages">               
                            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This part is angularjs code.

```
$scope.count = 1;
$scope.addChapter = function() {
    var iEl = angular.element( document.querySelector('#append-row') );
    var wEl = angular.element( document.querySelector('#clone-div') );
    iEl.append(wEl.clone());
    $scope.count+=1;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "post fields inside clone div" ?

Comment: where is that add button you mentioned?? and you your repeating your div??

Answer (score 1):

You should do cloning/repeating inside the template in a ng-repeat and have the data prepared beforehand, that is a much cleaner way. You'll notice for example in the template code you have, all the ng-model's are the same, and will always display the same information if you have 1 'clone' div or 100.

A better method would be to write your clone div in the template and use it as a repeatable ng-template 'script', for example:

```
// main template
<script type="text/ng-template" id="cloneable.html">
  // Your code here, but change reference to ng-model, ie this line as an example:
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="chapters.chapter[$index].title">
</script>

// main template, your new repeat then includes the repeatable script
<div ng-repeat="foo in manyFoos"
  ng-include="'cloneable.html'"></div>
```

This way you can use the $index that arises from ng-repeat, as part of the model to accurately separate each individual repeat block. In your controller, chapters.chapter will be an array of objects.

I don't know about the 'add' button part or what information you're adding, but the above should take care of the model problem you'll be encountering.